# How to get textfield value on button click from dynamic table view cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, swift5

So, I'm using `dequeueReusableCell` and will show several Table View with different row numbers of Current Price and and Change Price, depending on the product that I choose.
How do I get the value of the text field from Label change 1, 2, 3 etc?
Since it is a dynamic prototype, I do not know how to get the text field value when the `Change Price` button is clicked.

I have this class the connects the outlets

```
class priceListCell: UITableViewCell {
    // CURRENT PRICE
    @IBOutlet weak var lblProductNameCurrentPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtViewCurrentPrice: UITextView!

    // EDIT PRICE
    @IBOutlet weak var lblProductNameEditPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldEditPrice: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnChangePrice: UIButton!

}
```

And my TableView code is like this :

```
....
    case 1:
       if let editPriceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "editPriceCell", for: indexPath) as? priceListCell {
       let product = editProducts[indexPath.row]
       editPriceCell.lblProductNameEditPrice.text = product.productName
       return editPriceCell
    }
    case 2:
       if let changePriceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "changePriceCell", for: indexPath) as? priceListCell {
       return changePriceCell
    }
```

And here's my function to change price to firebase where i'm stuck at :

```
func changeValue() {
        for rowIndex in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 3) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: rowIndex, section: 3)

        }
    }
```

i'm stuck cause i don't know how to get the value of dynamic cell like this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `cellForRow` from `UITableView` and cast it as your class of `UITableViewCell` ie., `priceListCell` and then you can get your value from `UITableViewCell`, here's how:

```
func changeValue() {
    for rowIndex in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 3) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 3)
        if let editPriceCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? priceListCell {
            print(editPriceCell.lblProductNameEditPrice.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I got this error? `Exception: "Requested the number of rows for section (4) which is out of bounds."`

Comment: what are the numbers of sections ?

Comment: @AldoSugiarto You must be giving `0...tableView.numberOfRows` Are you sure you're giving `0..<tableView.numberOfRows` check the 2nd line in my answer clearly.

Comment: I have a mistake where the number of section is wrong. it should be (2) where the text field is in the section number 2. and I have check the `0...tableView.numberOfRows`.
it now has error like this : `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: here's my last code: 
`func changeValue() {
        for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 2) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowIndex, section: 2)
            if let editPriceCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as?  priceListCell {
                print(editPriceCell.txtFieldEditPrice.text)
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Read my previous comment. It say clearly what you're doing wrong here. Copy paste the code I've just given you and replace the 3 to 2.